# In httpclient what is the most elegant/correct way to turn HttpEntity to a String?

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I'm fetching a web page using the [Apache httpcomponents Java library](http://hc.apache.org/). After connecting the result I get is an [`HttpEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/class-use/HttpEntity.html) which has a method [`getContent()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent()) which returns an `InputStream` and also has a method `writeTo()` which writes to an OutputStream.

I want to turn the result into a String for extracting information. What is the most elegant (and safe) way to do this?

Some possible solutions:

- Write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then convert those bytes to a String with a String constructor
- use InputStreamReader to read straight from the stream, and put into a StringBuilder

Both of these feel a bit ugly. Would you recommend choosing one of these or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about (pseudo):

```
BasicResponseHandler handler = new org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler ();    
String str = httpClient.execute(request, handler);
```

You would have to handle exceptions on your own in this case.

Answer (score 6):

System.out.println( EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()) );

Comment: I think this here is the corrrect answer, the library provides the EntityUtils class for exactly this reason

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if you have already cleaned up the resources by calling the httpResponse.close() and want to get the string representation of the Entity elsewhere, using the above code will cause a "java.net.SocketException: socket closed" exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It may be ugly, but I think that's the only way to do it. You can use [IOUtils.toString()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) from Commons-IO though without having to write your own code.