# IOException closed stream error

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am getting error of **Error converting result `java.io.IOException Attempted read on closed stream`** what is the issue in it??

My JSONParsing class is as follows:

```
public class JSONParser {

  static InputStream is = null;
  static JSONObject jObj = null;
  static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public static JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method.equals("POST")){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String url1 = "http://192.168.0.29/evisiting_records/read_mytask.php?cid=1";
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url1);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.v("json from server ::",json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

 }
}
```

Kindly guide. how to resolve it?

Comment: Why do you have static variables when they could just be local variables? Why do you handle all exceptions by just logging them and then continuing as if everything was fine? Where is your current problem exception occurring?

Comment: b/c i am sending request to my EditText box which can just retrieve data from  it and it can't be use non static JSONObject.     cus_name_txtbx.setText(my_task.getString(TAG_NAME));    as my_task is JSONObject

Comment: it looks like you try to do something discussed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043580/in-httpclient-what-is-the-most-elegant-correct-way-to-turn-httpentity-to-a-strin

Comment: @Android: I think you've misunderstood how static variables work... and how exceptions are meant to be used.

Comment: What line of code throws the exception? What happens when you made the static variables local? What happens if the method is neither GET nor POST?